# Using Android Studio Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, android-studio

I am following the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/), however I am running into problems at step 3 "Import the SDK into an Android Studio Project". I imported the Module and set to compile as specified however, when I try to modify the settings.gradle I am running into problems.  It keeps giving me Gradle 'MyApplicationProject' project refresh failed:  You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle please use 1.6 or higher.  I am build the app with version 4.3 compiler while supporting all the way to 4.0(Android).
This is my settings.gradle

```
include ':MyPeeps'
include ':libraries:facebook', ':MyApplicationProject'
```

after is wasn't auto populating I added

```
    dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

Also put this into the build.gradle

```
     buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}
```

}

When I go to put in the onCreation command for facebook errors with all the commands that use the facebook api.  Does anyone know how I can fix my gradle issues?

Answer (score 0):

Change 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'

Comment: Still getting the same error, after changing that.
Gradle 'MyApplicationProject' project refresh failed: You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.6 or greater

Comment: Try running "./gradlew clean assemble" from your app's root directory, you make get a more useful error message

Comment: Run that in command prompt under the file directory?  I tried that and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to drop android studio and just go back to adt plugin got it work quickly at that point.  Thanks for the help.